# Authorization Header is blocked by cors Spring/Angular

Tags: angular, spring, authentication, jwt, cors

guys, i am developing my test application for interview and got one problem i didn't have before. I have me Spring server application and there is authorization using JWT-Token. And there are some controllers. I added annotation for each controller.

```
@CrossOrigin(
        origins = "*",
        allowedHeaders = {"Authorization", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "X-Requested-With", "content-type"},
        exposedHeaders = {"Authorization", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"},
        methods = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.DELETE, RequestMethod.PUT}
)
```

Tested all methods in postman and they work. When i try to authenticate from angular, sending request to my server, it works. But when a want to get another data(where already header Authentication is used) i get error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/sensors' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

But why, if i allowed header. This is my Angular service:

```
export class SensorsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getSensors(){
    let token = localStorage.getItem("token")
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    })

    const options = {headers}
    console.log(options)
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/sensors", options).subscribe(res => console.log(res))
  }
}
```

I started to dig and got next information from debugger(i don't know is it usefull). When i send request using postman, method resolveToken() on my server shows next:
[image]
But when i make request from angular client, i see next:
[image]
I can't understand where is the problem, if @CrossOrigin annotation exists and header, i pass to request in Angular is not null, i checked from console.

Comment: Open Network tab on your browser and see the request is send with header or not., You may see `OPTION` request from your browser, it's called Prefight request.

Comment: Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization. May be problem is that it has lower case for some reason?

Comment: I tryed to change at backend to lower case, but same error

Comment: You cannot call another enpoint/port from your angular app. Use a proxy instead.

Comment: can u say more exactly what u mean?

Comment: He means this one https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Comment: can u explain in which case i sould use it? i mean, to authentificate, i can make request to my server and get response, but when i pass header, it brakes, so i need to use this proxy when i pass header?